# Transpose notes / comments in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've a Google Sheet.  I've transposed the data.  Is there a way to also transpose any notes/comments that are attached to cells in the original data set?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets have two different features for handling notes/comments, one is called notes, the other is called comments.  While both could be attached to cells they could behave differently. Comments shows the profile picture of the user and have additional features like mentioning, mark as resolved, etc. that notes haven't.

- Copy-Paste : Only notes are included on the new position
- Copy-Paste as transposed : Only notes are included on the new position
- Cut-Paste : Both notes and comments are moved to the new position.
- Using formulas to transpose a range : Notes and comments aren't included

Google Apps Script could be used to transpose ranges and it will include notes but not comments.

Notes: Some documentation use the term comment to refer to notes.

Comment: Thank you for your help here.  I'm not so familiar with scripting etc.  Something I may need to learn!  Shame there's now easy way.

Comment: @Swotty Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

[Check out this thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604330/to-copy-the-cell-text-and-the-comments-to-another-sheet-using-google-apps-script)

> .moveTo(target) is able to move comments

So you can create a function in Tools > Script editor who'll transpose cells and keep the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your help here.  I'm not so familiar with scripting etc.  Something I may need to learn!  Shame there's now easy way.